# Windows 7 hangs during startup

Tags: windows-7, boot

When Windows *resumed from hibernation* I got a message

> Preparing to configure Windows.
>   Do not turn off your computer.

(Note that resuming from hibernation is supposed to restore the machine exactly as it was, it's not a time to install updates.) After two minutes this became

> Failure configuring Windows updates.
>   Reverting changes.
>   Do not turn off your computer.

This remained on the screen for a *full hour*, so I decided to turn off the computer after all.
Rebooting results in the same messages.

I tried to run repair from my installation DVD, but "startup repair could not detect a problem".
Booting in safe mode is no avail either.

How can I get Windows to startup properly? I don't seem to have restore points.

Comment: Did you try to boot into safe mode? Try that, and remove the latest installed updates. Edit: Do you have an idea of how many updates where installed? This reverting process can take a very long time and doesnt have to fail necessary when it takes long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Taking *doenoe*'s advice, I restarted the PC before going to bed last night (with the same messages I mentioned in OP), and lo and behold, this morning the PC was running fine.

So even unsolicited updates running bad can take a considerable time to undo.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to perform a roll back to before the updates were installed as it sounds like this is your issue.

If rolling back is not possible, try booting into safe mode, then uninstalling the latest updates

Comment: Windows *is* trying to roll back (that's what "reverting changes" means) and hangs, and I said that safe mode doesn't help. Thanks for your reply anyway.

Comment: Okay, Boot into your recovery CD and open a command prompt. Type sfc /scannow and press enter. This will scan for any corrupted files on your windows install